# Converting enum to runtime equivalent

Tags: java, enums

I have the following simple code which relies on an enum.

```
public enum Solvers {
    ALG1, ALG2
}

public class MyClass{
  private final EnumMap<Solvers, List<Solver>> solverInstancesPerSolver;
  private final Solvers[] invocationOrder={Solvers.ALG2,Solvers.ALG1};
...

  public void run(){
    for(Solvers solver : invocationOrder){
      List<Solver> solverInstances=solverInstancesPerSolver.get(solver);

      if(solver==Solvers.ALG1){
        doSomethingSpecial();
      }

    }

  }
}
```

I would like to convert this code to something that works during Runtime, where I don't know a priory which solvers there will be. Unfortunately, Enums can't be built during runtime, not even in a constructor.
A potential solution could be:

```
public class MyClass{
  private final Map<String, List<Solver>> solverInstancesPerSolver;
  private final String[] invocationOrder={"ALG2","ALG1"};

  public void run(){
    for(Solvers solver : invocationOrder){
      List<Solver> solverInstances=solverInstancesPerSolver.get(solver);

      if(solver.name.equals("ALG1"){
        doSomethingSpecial();
      }

    }

  }
}
```

This however is very ugly in my opinion. Imagine there is a typo:
private final String[] invokationOrder={"nonExistingAlg","ALG1"};
This will throw a runtime exception. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Where would the solver names (and instances) come from? Why would you use a different source to populate the array than the one you use to populate the map keys?

Comment: Why not declare Solvers as `class Solvers {String name; List<Solver> solvers;}`? That way you can create new ones at runtime and you don't need a map!